# function with a struct array pointer as an argument, C language

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

```
typedef struct {
    char manufacturer[SIZE];
    char model[SIZE];
    int size;
    int id;
    int qty;
    double cost;
    double price;
} tv;    

void firstSix(tv *tvarr[]);
void firstSix(tv *tvarr[])
{
    (*tvarr[0]).manufacturer = "Vizio";
}
```

I am making an inventory program. It consists of an array of structs that will store information about different televisions. In my program I am required to hardcode six entries into the array, so I am trying to make a function that will take a struct array pointer argument. In the above code, I included the struct declaration, the function prototype and function definition that I am trying to make. Everything is placed before and after main in the respective order. I don't understand why Visual Studio is highlighting the first parenthesis in the code inside the function definition and saying "expression must be a modifiable lvalue". I don't understand what it is that I am doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/arrayassign.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign an array like that. You need to do

`strcpy ((*tvarr[0]).manufacturer, "Vizio");`

Make sure that you don't go out of bounds when copying the string into the array.

You can either check the size of the string in advance or use `strncpy` which will limit the maximum number of characters to be copied.

An array is not a modifiable l-value. So basically you cannot have it on the left hand side of an assignment.

Or may be you also might want to define `manufacture` as `char *manufacture` and then dynamically allocate the string.

`manufacturer = strdup ("Vizio"); //manufacturer is char *`

Or depending on the length first allocate the buffer

`manufacturer = malloc (sizeof (char) * needed_bytes);`

Whenever you dynamically allocate the buffer, whenever you have finished working with it always remember to free it `free (manufacturer)`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to do something like

```
strncpy((tvarr[0])->manufacturer, "Vizio", SIZE - 1);
```

Kevin has it; you can't assign a string to a pointer, you must copy the data to the array. I suggest strncpy to keep from running off the end of the allocated space.